# Disabling and Enabling Foundation Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am working on a page that would allow users to enter an edit mode, in which dropdown forms appear when clicking on links, but I would like to disable this when users are not in editing mode. What I need to happen is for the data-dropdown attr to start as "disabled" but then be set to whatever id that corresponds with the form it should open, "drop25" for example. I have tried using both the attr and prop methods but haven't gotten very far. I can get them to start as disabled, but if I try to edit the attribute in a click handler it doesn't seem to work, even when the source says they change.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').attr('data-dropdown', 'disabled');

    $(document).on("click", ":button.edit", function() {
        //Enter Edit mode
        if (editMode == false) {
            editMode = true;
            //when editing, enable dropdown
            $('a').attr('data-dropdown', 'drop1');
        }
        else {
             //turn off editing mode
             editMode = false;
             //disable dropdown
             $('a').attr('data-dropdown', 'disabled');
         }
    });
});
```

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible? Should I instead maybe just use another type of dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve my problem

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        if (editMode == false && $('.f-dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
             window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        };
```

As you can see, I added a click handler to all links, if the user isn't in edit mode and the foundation dropdown is open (which happens when you click on a link connected to a dropdown), trigger a click function on the link to close the dropdown and then visit the link that was clicked on.